# How can I determine if a string in Django model list field contains a substring?

Tags: python, django

How do I write a filter like this:

```py
MyObject.objects.filter(some_string__icontains="match")
```

for each string in a Postgres ArrayField like this:

```py
MyObject.objects.filter(some_arrayfield__icontains="match")  # Not working
```

So if *some_arrayfield* in a *MyObject* looks like this:

```py
some_arrayfield = ["item1", "item2", "item3match"]
```

the query above should find it

Comment: What is the type of `some_list` field? There are no 'list' fields per se

Comment: It's a Postgres ArrayField

Comment: I tested `some_arrayfield__icontains="match"` locally and it's working, can you provide more information? For example, basic model structure, what data do you have in database, where do you call `.objects.filter`, what data does it return and what data do you expect?